# MSB6001: Invalid command line switch for "cmd.exe". | Qt + Windows Phone RT

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-studio-2013, store

Hi I've got problem with Visual Studio Express 2013. When I want to compile the code it drive me crazy. Beacause I was serching for solution of this Error:

```
Error   1   error MSB6001: Invalid command line switch for "cmd.exe". Illegal characters in path.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  170 5   TabliceChemiczne
```

I can compile the code using Qt and deploy on the device. The app looks great but I cannot deploy it to the shop. One reason of that is the assets file is not avaible during the developer console:

```
Package acceptance validation error: The following image(s) specified in the appxManifest.xml of 13084Artmetic.TablicaMendelejewa-Artmetic_1q966j2m0cjrj.appx were not found: assets/logo_71x71.png, assets/logo_150x150.png, assets/logo_71x71.png, assets/logo_310x150.png, assets/logo_480x800.png
```

but in fact the are in the package, because I found it manually.
And the second reason is that I cannot add Signature to a package:

```
Package acceptance validation error: The package 13084Artmetic.TablicaMendelejewa-Artmetic_1q966j2m0cjrj.appx uses an incorrect hash algorithm: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512. Packages must use SHA-256 as the hash algorithm.
```

so I decided to install Visual Studio agter trying to create Signature using command prompt, but I cannot compile the code during the error that relates to this xml code:

```
 <Target Name="CustomBuild"
          Condition="'@(CustomBuild)' != ''"
          DependsOnTargets="SelectCustomBuild;ComputeCustomBuildOutput"
          BeforeTargets="$(CustomBuildToolBeforeTargets)"
          AfterTargets="$(CustomBuildToolAfterTargets)"
          >

    <PropertyGroup>
      <CustomBuildToolArchitecture Condition="'$(CustomBuildToolArchitecture)' == ''">Native32Bit</CustomBuildToolArchitecture>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <CustomBuild
      Sources                     ="@(CustomBuild)"
      BuildSuffix                 ="$(_BuildSuffix)"

      TrackerLogDirectory         ="%(CustomBuild.TrackerLogDirectory)"
      MinimalRebuildFromTracking  ="%(CustomBuild.MinimalRebuildFromTracking)"

      TLogReadFiles               ="@(CustomBuildTLogReadFiles)"
      TLogWriteFiles              ="@(CustomBuildTLogWriteFiles)"
      TrackFileAccess             ="$(TrackFileAccess)"
      ToolArchitecture            ="$(CustomBuildToolArchitecture)"
      TrackerFrameworkPath        ="$(CustomBuildTrackerFrameworkPath)"
      TrackerSdkPath              ="$(CustomBuildTrackerSdkPath)"

      AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes  ="%(CustomBuild.AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes)"
      >
    </CustomBuild>
```